# Android G Pay check if any credit cards is add

Tags: android, google-pay

I try to find Solutions and I can not. Is it possible to check if in my google wallets I added credit cards?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear. If you are talking about integrating the Google Pay button into your Android app and checking to see if the use has a supported payment method, you can use `isReadyToPay` with `existingPaymentMethodRequired` set to `true`. See https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/client#isReadyToPay

Note that in the `TEST` environment, `isReadyToPay` returns `true`. You need to switch over to `PRODUCTION` to get the actual value.